# How to use the Hijri date of my area in Android?

Tags: java, android, calendar, hijri

I'm using this:

```
HijrahDate hijrahDate = HijrahDate.now();
```

But it shows the Hijri date of Umalqura calendar of Saudi Arabia. How can I use the Hijri date for my country?

Comment: It’s not built in. There may be libraries that can give you that. One option I’d look into would be [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date picker for hijri(islamic) calender in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906916/date-picker-for-hijriislamic-calender-in-android)